# Complex data set from mysql using active record in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

i am generating  a invoice generation application. In that, i have a table that stores individual items of invoice with flags buyer and invoice_no. These flags help me get a aggregate invoice construct from rows. This is the function:

```
public function invoice_get()
{
    $data=array();


    $this->db->group_by('invoice_no');
    $this->db->order_by('invoice_no','asc');
    $Q=$this->db->get('sales');
    echo $Q->num_rows();
    if($Q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($Q->result_array() as $row)
        {

            if(!isset($data[$row['invoice_no']]))
            {
                $data[$row['invoice_no']]['date']=$row['date'];
                $this->db->where('id',$row['buyer']);
                $q=$this->db->get('ledgers');
                $data[$row['invoice_no']]['buyer']=$q->row();
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->where('id',$row['item_id']);
                $i=$this->db->get('inventory');
                $data[$row['invoice_no']]['items'][$row['item_id']]=$i->row();

            }

        }
        print_r($data);
        //$this->response($data);
    }


}
```

The problem is that i am not getting item details
What may be the mistake?

Comment: Some pretty ugly nestings here. I am sure that it can be done in a lot simple way.

Comment: @itachi Suggest something then :) Hope you got the whole idea of fetching records this way.

Comment: No. I didn't get the idea here. You are checking for some index in $data where as $data will always be an empty array unless you assign something which you didn't. So what's the purpose of that `isset`?

Comment: This design has some flaws. If you noticed, for every row returned, another query is run. If you return just 100 rows, it'l run another 100 queries. Going by your query builder, it doesn't look complicated enough which needs so much queries to run. The best i can offer is an alternative solution provided you give the table with sample datas and expected output. I won't be lying, your code is a little bit unreadable for me and follow every index there after which also goes under some conditions.

Comment: see what i am trying to do is that i am trying to gnereate a dataset in which one entity (element) represents one invoice details. The table i have contains rows of individual items in the invoice. Each row has invoice_number and buyer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24188/discussion-between-mrinal-purohit-and-itachi)

Comment: To make it easier, you should give table with sample datas and expected output. As of now, from above code, i think no one will try to dig that deep to come up with a solution. If you'l give it, it'l be way easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i = 1; 
foreach ($q->result_array() as $row){

$data[$row['invoice_number']]['date'] = $row['date'];
$data[$row['invoice_number']]['buyer']['id'] = $row['id'];
$data[$row['invoice_number']]['item'][$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
$data[$row['invoice_number']]['item'][$i]['description'] = $row['description']; 
//and more if you want to add....
$i++;

}
```

This should give you the desired result.